# Fluid boxes of equal height

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem creating boxes of equal height for bootstrap 3. In the beginning, I had issues with image sizes being different, so I tried hacking it via JS and resizing them on the fly. The problem is that if there is no cache for the image, JS fails and screws up the layout even more. I ended up resizing all images to 700 x 700 pixels, but the problem is still there since the accompanying text might be of various lengths.

I created an example in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7yqkgm2c/

I am not good with CSS and I am wondering if you will be able to help me with solution.

This is the JS that I used to make all boxes the same height (remove it from the fiddle)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                //function that calculates height and makes all boxes same height. Issue- imeges that are not cached, screwing up the layout
                var heights = $(".thumbnail").map(function () {
                    return $(this).height();
                }).get(),
                        maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
                $(".thumbnail").height(maxHeight + 15);
                //end same height products                
            });
```

This is the result that I want to achieve (or propose your solution if you think you know how to approach it better):
[image: example]

Comment: would min-height : 123px  work for you? in the css?

Comment: Do you have control over the markup? I've noticed a lot of superfluous divs and bootstrap classes in the HTML which could be removed in order to make the CSS task easier.

Comment: Yes, I do. It is the result of me fighting with it.. messed it up pretty good

Comment: Don't fight bootstrap - I've seen that happen in a recent project and the code quickly became unusable. I had to pick up the pieces :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhkmyaf3/18/

Assuming you are in control of the markup, I cleaned up how each product might look:

```
<div class='product-container col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3'> 
        <div class='item'>
            <img src='http://placehold.it/700x700' />
            <div class='item-text'>
                <h5>Product Title</h5>
                <p>Product description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div><!-- end of item-text -->
            <div class='price-point'>
                <div class='price'>$100</div>
                <a class='btn btn-info' href='#'>View</a>
            </div><!-- end of price-point -->
        </div><!-- end of item -->
    </div><!-- end of product-container -->
```

The `product-container` div is used once for each product, and all product-container divs appear inside a div called `items-row`. You would repeat the items-row div if you wanted a new row of products, but since you are using bootstrap this isn't strictly necessary as the products should stack.

I only included the basic CSS you would need for the structure, plus a bit of padding/borders etc for clarification. The key CSS to achieve the equalised heights you want is the use of `display:flex` :

```
.items-row, .product-container {
    display: webkit-box;
    display: moz-box;
    display: ms-flexbox;
    display: webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

As shown in the example, you would need to cancel the `display:flex` and replace with `display:block` for any device where you wish the products to stack in a single-column. The fiddle linked above should demonstrate that your image size and product description can be quite flexible while still maintaining equalised heights.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the product description or title a min-height property. Regardless of how much text they contain, the height will always match up.

I have created a class called "product-description" and given it a min-height of 95 pixels. This only affects the text underneath the title but you can do the same for the product name if you need to.

You can then use media queries to target different sizes and adjust these values accordingly.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="categories-list" class="row list-group">


                            <div class="productlist">
                            <div class="item col-md-2">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="group list-group-image thumb1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=700%C3%97700&w=700&h=700" alt="" />
                                    <div class="caption">
                                         <span><h5 class="group inner list-group-item-heading" alt="">PRODUCT NAME VERY LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG</h5></span>
                                         <div class="rating" id="id' . $Value["id"] . '" data-val="' . $Value["average_rating"] . '" data-input=".rating-value" ></div>
                                        <p class="group inner list-group-item-text ">Model: 12345</p>
                                        <p class="group inner product-description">Text goes here</p>
                                        <div class="row bottom_align">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <p class="lead">$19.95</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>     
                             </div>     


                                <div class="productlist">
                            <div class="item col-md-2">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="group list-group-image thumb1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=700%C3%97700&w=700&h=700" alt="" />
                                    <div class="caption">
                                         <span><h5 class="group inner list-group-item-heading" alt="">PRODUCT NAME</h5></span>
                                         <div class="rating" id="id' . $Value["id"] . '" data-val="' . $Value["average_rating"] . '" data-input=".rating-value" ></div>
                                        <p class="group inner list-group-item-text ">Model: 12345</p>
                                        <p class="group inner product-description">Text goes here</p>
                                        <div class="row bottom_align">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <p class="lead">$19.95</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>     
                             </div>     

                                <div class="productlist">
                            <div class="item col-md-2">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="group list-group-image thumb1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=700%C3%97700&w=700&h=700" alt="" />
                                    <div class="caption">
                                         <span><h5 class="group inner list-group-item-heading" alt="">PRODUCT NAME</h5></span>
                                         <div class="rating" id="id' . $Value["id"] . '" data-val="' . $Value["average_rating"] . '" data-input=".rating-value" ></div>
                                        <p class="group inner list-group-item-text ">Model: 12345grhj 4567u456uy4567g</p>
                                        <p class="group inner product-description">Text goes here</p>
                                        <div class="row bottom_align">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <p class="lead">$19.95</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>     
                             </div>     

                                <div class="productlist">
                            <div class="item col-md-2">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="group list-group-image thumb1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=700%C3%97700&w=700&h=700" alt="" />
                                    <div class="caption">
                                         <span><h5 class="group inner list-group-item-heading" alt="">PRODUCT NAME</h5></span>
                                         <div class="rating" id="id' . $Value["id"] . '" data-val="' . $Value["average_rating"] . '" data-input=".rating-value" ></div>
                                        <p class="group inner list-group-item-text ">Model: 12345</p>
                                        <p class="group inner product-description">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here </p>
                                        <div class="row bottom_align">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <p class="lead">$19.95</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>     
                             </div>     

                                <div class="productlist">
                            <div class="item col-md-2">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="group list-group-image thumb1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=700%C3%97700&w=700&h=700" alt="" />
                                    <div class="caption">
                                         <span><h5 class="group inner list-group-item-heading" alt="">PRODUCT NAME</h5></span>
                                         <div class="rating" id="id' . $Value["id"] . '" data-val="' . $Value["average_rating"] . '" data-input=".rating-value" ></div>
                                        <p class="group inner list-group-item-text ">Model: 12345</p>
                                        <p class="group inner product-description">Text goes here</p>
                                        <div class="row bottom_align">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <p class="lead">$19.95</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>     
                             </div>     

                                <div class="productlist">
                            <div class="item col-md-2">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="group list-group-image thumb1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=700%C3%97700&w=700&h=700" alt="" />
                                    <div class="caption">
                                         <span><h5 class="group inner list-group-item-heading" alt="">PRODUCT NAME</h5></span>
                                         <div class="rating" id="id' . $Value["id"] . '" data-val="' . $Value["average_rating"] . '" data-input=".rating-value" ></div>
                                        <p class="group inner list-group-item-text ">Model: 12345</p>
                                        <p class="group inner product-description">Text goes here</p>
                                        <div class="row bottom_align">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <p class="lead">$1</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>     
                             </div>     

                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        font-size: 12px;
        /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */        
    }

    html * {
        outline: 0 !important;
    }


    .ui-pnotify {
        padding-top: 70px;        
    }   

    /* make sidebar nav vertical */ 
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .sidebar-nav .navbar .navbar-collapse {
            padding: 0;
            max-height: none;
        }
        .sidebar-nav .navbar ul {
            float: none;
        }
        .sidebar-nav .navbar ul:not {
            display: block;
        }
        .sidebar-nav .navbar li {
            float: none;
            display: block;
        }
        .sidebar-nav .navbar li a {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
        }
    }

    .top5 { margin-top:5px; }
    .top7 { margin-top:7px; }
    .top10 { margin-top:10px; }
    .top15 { margin-top:15px; }
    .top17 { margin-top:17px; }
    .top30 { margin-top:30px; }

.glyphicon { margin-right:5px; }
            .thumbnail
            {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                padding: 0px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
                -moz-border-radius: 0px;
                border-radius: 0px;
            }

            .item.list-group-item
            {
                float: none;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #fff;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .item.list-group-item:nth-of-type(odd):hover,.item.list-group-item:hover
            {
                background: #428bca;
            }

            .item.list-group-item .list-group-image
            {
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            .item.list-group-item .thumbnail
            {
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
            .item.list-group-item .caption
            {
                padding: 9px 9px 0px 9px;
            }
            .item.list-group-item:nth-of-type(odd)
            {
                background: #eeeeee;
            }

            .item.list-group-item:before, .item.list-group-item:after
            {
                display: table;
                content: " ";
            }

            .item.list-group-item img
            {
                float: left;
            }
            .item.list-group-item:after
            {
                clear: both;
            }
            .list-group-item-text
            {
                margin: 0 0 10px;
            }

            /*           PANEL COLLAPSE */
            .panel-heading a:after {
                font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
                content:"\e114";
                float: right;
                color: grey;
            }
            .panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
                content:"\e080";
            }
            /*           PANEL COLLAPSE */


            .filters {
                max-height:165px;
                overflow-y:auto; 
            }

            .bottom_align{
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 3px;
                margin-bottom: 10;       
                bottom: 10px;
            }

            .thumb1 { 
                width: 250px;
                height: 250px;
            }

.product-description {
    min-height: 95px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yqkgm2c/1/)